# R: value preceding a change

Tags: r, diff

The following code splits `test` into the numbers following a decrease, increase or no change.

```
test <- c(1,2,3,4,5,5,4,1,2,3)
ifelse(diff(test)>0, "up", ifelse(diff(test)<0, "down", "no change"))

[1] "up" "up" "up" "up" "no change" "down" "down" "up" "up"
```

However, rather than getting the result of a change, I need `"up"`, `"down"` or `"no change"` to reflect the number preceding the change.

For example, the last `1` in the above set would be up, because it's followed by a higher number.

I've tried various lags, but as it doesn't change the logic of the `if` statement it hasn't worked. Is there a way to do this?

Edit:

The expected output is similar to the output shown in the example above, but rather than dropping the first number due to it having no predecessor, the last figure is excluded because there is no change following it.

Really hope that made sense, but if not I'll do my best to clarify further.

Comment: For clarity, what is the full vector of your expected results?

Comment: Per the edit, isn't that just a matter of perspective? Wouldn't the output be the same?

Comment: The same question of @JasonAizkalns still holds. What are you looking for exactly? i.e. the final resultant vector

Comment: @AndrewTaylorThe problem occurs when I want to link the number followed by up with another column. The corresponding number would be different. It also fails to capture the initial value and what change it is followed by. While the output vector visually looks the same, it represents the wrong number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`diff(x)` returns an array of length one less than `x`, so that `diff(x)[i]=x[i+1]-x[i]`.  Whether you want to consider this the change "before i+1" or the change "after i" makes no difference, it's still the same value.

If you want to get back an array of the same length as your input, for your case try either `c("no change", result)` or `c(result, "no change")`, which will pad the result to be the same length as the input, and signify either that "no change" occurs before the first entry, or that "no change" occurs after the last entry.  I can't figure out which one of these is the one you want, but it should be one of the two.

Comment: Thanks for that! It's at the tail end of a long day here and that simple solution did not occur to me at all.